# Let $Z$ be a continuous random variable and let $M = \max{\{Z,1-Z\}}$. What is the density of $M$?

Tags: probability

> Let $Z$ be a continuous random variable with density function non zero on $(0,1)$ and let $M = \max{\{Z,1-Z\}}$. I want to find the density of $M$.

This is what I have done:

\begin{align*}F_M(t) &= \mathbb{P}(M \leq t) = \mathbb{P}(\max{\{Z,1-z\}} \leq t)\\&
 = \mathbb{P}(z \leq t)\mathbb{P}(1-z \leq t)\\&= \mathbb{P}(z \leq t) - \mathbb{P}(z \leq t)\mathbb{P}(z \leq 1-t) 
\end{align*}

Now I try to find $f_M(t)$ by deriving: 
$$ f_M(t) = f_Z(t) - [f_z(t) F_z(1-t) + F_z(t)f_z(1-t) ]$$
But I do not know how to go on from here.

Any hints?

Comment: How do you get the third equality? It looks like your are using independence of $Z$ and $1-Z$ (they are *not* independent).

Comment: $Z$ and $1-Z$ are not independent, so you first step is not justified.

Comment: That's right. How should I go from there then?

Comment: $$\mathbb{P}\{\max(Z,1-Z)\leq t\} = \mathbb{P}\{1-t \leq Z \leq t\} = F_Z(t) - F_Z(1-t)$$for $t\geq 1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
F_M(t)=P(\max{\{Z,1-Z\}}\le t)&=P(Z\le t, 1-Z\le t)=P(Z\le t, 1-t\le Z)\\&=P(1-t\le Z\le t)=\begin{cases}0, \text{if } 1-t>t\\[0.2cm]\int_{1-t}^tf_z(x)dx, \text{if } 1-t\le t\end{cases}\\[0.2cm]&=\begin{cases}0, \text{if } t<1/2\\F_Z(t)-F_Z(1-t), \text{if } t\ge 1/2\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Hence, $$f_M(t)=f_Z(t)+f_Z(1-t)$$ for $t\ge 1/2$ and $f_M(t)=0$, otherwise.